# Фрейм не открывается ERR_BLOCKED_BY_RESPONSE

Tags: iframe

Хостинг на рег ру и сайт на тильде, пытаюсь фреймом вставить скрипт и не выходит, какой код нужно вставить в тильде чтобы не было ERR_BLOCKED_BY_RESPONSE

Comment: Есть кто знает ?

Answer (score 2):

Все дело в заголовке HTTP [X-Frame-Options](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Frame-Options) ресурса, который вы хотите показать в фрейме. В нем указано, что либо страница не может быть использована как фрейм (значение DENY), либо что может, но только с того же домена (значение SAMEORIGIN).

Уберите этот заголовок HTTP.

Comment: Подскажите пожалуйста какой код я могу вставить в HEAD странице одного сайта что-бы на втором сайте он открылся

Comment: Речь именно о заголовках HTTP (HTTP headers), а не об элементах HTML в `head`.